# Doctrine 2 ArrayCollection - how to find and modify a specific element

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a `Cart` entity that contains an `ArrayCollection` of `CartItems`.  The relationship in code -

Cart.php:

```
class Cart
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CartItem", mappedBy="cart")
     */
    private $cartItems;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->cartItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

`CartItems` are essentially a DB pointer (for lack of a better term) to a `Product` entity, with an additional `quantity` field.

CartItem.php:

```
class CartItem
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", inversedBy="cartItems")
     */
    private $cart;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="You must specify how much of the item you wish to buy")
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/", message="The quantity must be a number")
     */
    private $quantity;
}
```

In my app, when a user wants to add a `Product` to their `Cart`, I want to check to see if that particular `Product` is already one of the `CartItems`.  If so, I want to increase the `quantity`, otherwise add it to the collection.  I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

`ArrayCollection` methods `exists` and `contains` simply return true/false.  Given my setup, I'm not sure what I'd use as a key for the collection.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `CartItems` for new `Product`. If filtered `CartItems` is not empty increase the `quantity`, otherwise add new CartItem.

```
$newProduct // Product Object 

$cartItems = $cart->getCartItems()->filter(function(CartItem $cartItem) (use $newProduct) {
    return $cartItem->getProduct() === $newProduct;
});

if ($cartItems->count()) {
    foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        $cartItem->setQuantity($cartItem->getQuantity() + 1);
    }
} else {
    $cart->addCartItem(
        (new CartItem())
            ->setProduct($newProduct)
            ->setQuantity(1)
    );
}
```

Comment: This seems nice but you have a typo: `use ($newProduct)` instead of wrapping the whole thing together^^